# Join statement using 2 databases on an sql server will not accept database name as a variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am currently trying to use an sql join statement to bring back results needed for my program. When i try to change one of the database names to a variable, it is displaying an exception of "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0X80131904): Incorrect syntax near '.'" Both databases are on the same SQL server. If i use one of the database names in the string, it connects and the statement is executed as intended. This only occurs when i put the database name as a parameter:

```
   using (var command = new SqlCommand("select p.Tablefield, P.TableFeild, es.SynchronousIn, es.SynchronousOut, " +
                                                "es.dddd, es.MessageName, es.MessageDate from database.xxx.xxx es " +
                                                "join @Database.dbo.xxxx p on p.GUID = es.dddd where es.MessageName = @MessageType and " +
                                                "(es.MessageDate >= @date and es.MessageDate < @date)" +
                                                "and es.dddd = @ddddd " +
                                                "order by MessageDate DESC" , connection))
```

The @Database Parameter is defined afterwards:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Database", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
command.Parameters["@Database"].Value = DatabaseName;
```

Any ideas at all? I know this might not be the best way of doing this, I am pretty new to the SQL aspect of c# and would like to know if this is possible. I have replaced certain fields with XXXX or DDDD as this is a tool i am hoping to write for my company.

Comment: "(es.MessageDate >= @date and es.MessageDate < @date)" missing space at the end?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the issue occurs around the database name, as i have changed this for one of the names and the statement executed correctly. i do have an issue with the message dates, the search brings no results but i will resolve that after i have fixed this problem.

Comment: Is the database / table table correct?

Comment: I would try replacing what yu have with a simply select count(1) from the first table in (database.xxx.xxx es) and get that t work first.

Comment: IIRC You can't use database/table/column names as parameters without dynamic sql/replacing in the string.

Comment: It is as @Bridge says. You'll need to dynamically build the SQL string, and replace it.

Comment: @ pm_2 :Yes it is, I have used the name of the database instead of the parameter and all works fine. I have stepped through the code and ensured that this is the same also.

Comment: @Bridge How would you go about doing that? Would you have any example code at all?

Comment: Replace it in your command string in your .net code before sending it to the db

Comment: As @AllanS.Hansen says do this from your front-end - follow one of the posted answers below, both of which should work. Remember to accept one of them if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass the database name as a parameter. You can add it using `String.Format` on the sql command string.

Something like this:

```
String.Format("select p.Tablefield, P.TableFeild, es.SynchronousIn, es.SynchronousOut, " +
"es.dddd, es.MessageName, es.MessageDate from database.xxx.xxx es " +
"join {0}.dbo.xxxx p on p.GUID = es.dddd where es.MessageName = @MessageType and " +
"(es.MessageDate >= @date and es.MessageDate < @date)" + "and es.dddd = @ddddd " +
"order by MessageDate DESC", DatabaseName);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! worked a treat Unfortunately my reputation level prevents me from marking this as useful

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

```
String.Format("select p.Tablefield, P.TableFeild, es.SynchronousIn, es.SynchronousOut, " +
"es.dddd, es.MessageName, es.MessageDate from database.xxx.xxx es " +
"join {0}.dbo.xxxx p on p.GUID = es.dddd where es.MessageName = @MessageType and " +
"(es.MessageDate >= @date and es.MessageDate < @date)" + "and es.dddd = @ddddd " +
"order by MessageDate DESC", DatabaseName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the table name as a parameter. You could just insert the table name into the SQL string using `string.Format`. Something like..

```
 using (var command = new SqlCommand("select p.Tablefield, P.TableFeild, es.SynchronousIn, es.SynchronousOut, " +
                                            "es.dddd, es.MessageName, es.MessageDate from database.xxx.xxx es " +
                                            string.Format("join @{0}.dbo.{1} p on p.GUID = es.dddd where es.MessageName = @MessageType and ",databaseName,tableName) +
                                            "(es.MessageDate >= @date and es.MessageDate < @date)" +
                                            "and es.dddd = @ddddd " +
                                            "order by MessageDate DESC" , connection))
```

Be sure to check this value for SQL injection if it is in any way manipulated from the user interface.

Comment: As above, Thanks for that! worked a treat Unfortunately my reputation level prevents me from marking this as useful